# Variable assignment before declaration

Tags: python

I have this piece of code:

```
x = 3

if x == 2:
    global L, M, S
    L, M, S =   -1.982373595    ,   16.54777487     ,   0.080127429 

elif x == 3:
    global L, M, S
    L, M, S =   -1.419991255    ,   16.00030401     ,   0.072634432 

elif x == 4:
    global L, M, S
    L, M, S =   -1.714869347    ,   15.62817269 ,   0.071889214

print(L, M, S)
```

I always get a SyntaxError for line 7 (`SyntaxError: name 'L' is assigned to before global declaration`).

Comment: You shouldn't use `global` declaration in this case, just remove them declarations

Comment: Yeah I understand your point but this is just only a Fraction of my full code where I would need global declaration

Comment: @KOSMOS you never *need* `global`. Indeed, it is generally considered a bad practice (global, mutable state). But the point the commenter was making is that you *don't need it here because you are already in the global scope so it does nothing useful*

Comment: In Short this code here is in a Function and I want to use it later in an other Function again sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: Your function should *return* values that the caller can assign to `L`, `M`, and `S`, if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove `global` lines from the code. However if you are using a function then use it like this:

```
L, M, S = 0, 0, 0


def foo(x):
    global L, M, S
    if x == 2:
        L, M, S = -1.982373595,   16.54777487,   0.080127429

    elif x == 3:
        L, M, S = -1.419991255,   16.00030401,   0.072634432

    elif x == 4:
        L, M, S = -1.714869347,   15.62817269,   0.071889214


foo(3)
print(L, M, S)
```

Answer (score 0):

The global declaration is unnecessary. Something like this should solve your problem.

```
x = 3

if x == 2:
    L, M, S =   -1.982373595    ,   16.54777487     ,   0.080127429 

elif x == 3:
    L, M, S =   -1.419991255    ,   16.00030401     ,   0.072634432 

elif x == 4:
    L, M, S =   -1.714869347    ,   15.62817269 ,   0.071889214

print(L, M, S)
```

That being said, you should probably define L,M,S as something in the null case that none of the ifs are called, so that your file never returns them before assignment. Maybe add something like :

```
...

else:
    L,M,S = none, none, none

print(L, M, S)
```

Below is a useful resource about the global keyword.

https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/global-keyword